# Configuring git-flow hook for pre-release using SourceTree?

Tags: npm, githooks, git-flow

Is there a way that I can configure hooks to run a set of commands *before* a release is committed to a version when using Git Flow in SourceTree? I want to be able to make sure that when the last commit before a release is committed that `npm run prod` is ran to compile my Webpack assets instead leaving the results of `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to deal with this is not git hooks but to actually run `git flow release start #.#.#` then `npm run production` followed by the commit and `git flow release  finish '#.#.#'`. This also makes it so that I can verify the contents of the minified files work in the website before I release.